# Concatenate second column rows for the matching values in First column and generate file

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have requirement of generate file (individual file) based on the first column values .

Source File is like

```
Batch No ; Values 
-------------------
B1       ; TEST1
B1       ; TEST2
B1       ; TEST3
B2       ; DELTA1
B2       ; DELTA2
```

expected output would be two files

1. B1.txt (this contains)

   ```
   TEST1
   TEST2
   TEST3
   ```
2. B2.txt (this contains)

   ```
   DELTA1
   DELTA1
   ```

The source file data will vary every time but structure (the number of columns and delimiter) will be consistent

Any suggestion?

Comment: What have you tried? How did it fail?

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk for this.

```
awk -F" *; *" 'NR > 2{print $2 > $1 ".txt"}' source.txt
```

This asumes your source file is `source.txt` and contains

```
Batch No ; Values 
-------------------
B1       ; TEST1
B1       ; TEST2
B1       ; TEST3
B2       ; DELTA1
B2       ; DELTA2
```

The result are two files: `B1.txt` and `B2.txt`

- `-F" *; *"`: Defines the field separator. In this case a semicolon and any number of spaces before and after the semicolon.
- `NR > 2`: You skip first two rows.
- `$1`, `$2` stores the content of the first and second columns respectively.
- With `>` you redirect the output of the `print` command to the corresponding file instead of printing to the standard output.

Answer (score 0):

This is a one liner with awk:

```
tail -n +3 test.txt | awk '{print $3>$1".txt"}'
```

The tail `-n +3` removes the first 2 lines of header; the awk scripts prints the value of the 3rd field in a file named after the first field concatenated with `.txt`

The default awk field separator is spaces, so in your example, the `;` is field #2 which we drop. The input file does not even have to be sorted by the first field for this to work.

Comment: or `awk 'NR>2{print $3>$1".txt"}' test.txt`

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r file data; do
    echo "${data#; *}" >> "$file".txt
done < <(sed -n -e '1,/^---/!p' source_file)
```